# Equivalence relations->Showing that a set is reflexive, symmetric and transitive

Tags: equivalence-relations

**For each of the following sets A and binary relations  ~, decide whether ~ defines an equivalence relation on $A$**

**a)** Set $A=\mathbb{R}$
Relation: $x\sim y$ if $x=ay$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: “Reflexive”, “symmetric”, and “transitive” are usually properties of (binary) relations. While binary relations are “sets”, you want to specify that you are talking about *relations*, and not sets in general.

Comment: You should not use the letter $a$ to mean different things. Instead, you can use another letter $b$ to also be a rational number, for example "$x = ay$ for some $a\in \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ then $y=bx$ where $b=1/a\in \mathbb{Q}"$

Comment: Remember also that examples can not be proofs. In your symmetry argument you rely on the fact that if $a\in \mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ then $1/a\in \mathbb{Q}$ which does not account for the case $a=0$, does $a=0$ break the symmetry or is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Proof for (b) is the same as in the proposed dupe since $\Bbb Q$ is a multiplicative subgroup  of $\Bbb R$, and the counterexample for (a) comes from looking at where the proof breaks down when you adjoin the *noninvertible* element $0$,  destroying the group structure (as hinted in Andre's comment).

Comment: For $y \ne 0$ in part a, $0 \sim y$ but $y \not\sim 0$.

Comment: This post seems rather similar to one part of your question: [Prove that $E$ is an equivalence relation, where $E$ is given by $qr=s$ for some $q\in\mathbb Q^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2565467)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include the number $0$ you get $\;0\sim y\;$ with $\;0=0\cdot y\;$ for any $\;y\in\mathbb{R}\;$. Though, if $\;y\neq 0\;$, you never get $\;y\sim 0\;$, as $\;a\cdot 0=0\neq y\;$ for all $\;a\in\mathbb{Q}\;$. What follows, is that under the inclusion of $0$, the symmetry won't hold.

If you remove the $0$, as shown in case (b), you maintain the symmetry, given that for all $\;a\in\mathbb{Q}\;$ where $\;a\neq 0\;$, there exists a multiplicative inverse $\;a^{-1}\;$, such that $\;x=ay\iff y=a^{-1}x\;$, or $\;x\sim y\implies y\sim x\;$. The above exception won't be a problem anymore, since $\;0\sim y\iff 0=ay\iff y=0\;$.